# Select column header and first column of a cell in datagridview when selected

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I need to change the color of the Header Cell and first column called "col_row" when one or more cells are selected with the mouse like this:

[image]

I use this code and its working:

```
    Private Sub gdv_PatioAcopio_CellStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs) Handles gdv_PatioAcopio.CellStateChanged
    If e.Cell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        e.Cell.Selected = False
    Else

        If e.Cell.Selected = True Then
            Me.gdv_PatioAcopio.Columns(e.Cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            Me.gdv_PatioAcopio.Rows(e.Cell.RowIndex).Cells("col_row").Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        ElseIf e.Cell.Selected = False Then
            Me.gdv_PatioAcopio.Columns(e.Cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Navy
            Me.gdv_PatioAcopio.Rows(e.Cell.RowIndex).Cells("col_row").Style.BackColor = Color.Navy
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

but when i deselect, for example, the third column, the first column changes its color to the original color.

[image]

How can i prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the entire column and the entire row for selected cells before changing the `Columns(e.Cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor` and the `Rows(e.Cell.RowIndex).Cells("col_row").Style.BackColor` respectively.

Just because `e.Cell.Selected` changed doesn't mean that it was the *only* cell forcing the column and row to be `Selected`.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellStateChanged
    If e.Cell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        e.Cell.Selected = False
    Else

        Dim rowSelected As Boolean = False
        Dim colSelected As Boolean = False

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells(e.Cell.ColumnIndex).Selected Then
                colSelected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.Cell.RowIndex).Cells
            If cell.Selected Then
                rowSelected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(e.Cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = If(colSelected, Color.LightBlue, Color.Navy)
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.Cell.RowIndex).Cells("col_row").Style.BackColor = If(rowSelected, Color.LightBlue, Color.Navy)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: GIF selecting/deselecting cells]

Comment: That's exactly what i did haha thanks anyway, even though its a bit slow when you drag the mouse over the gridview, does its job.

Comment: I noticed that too. I'm sure there's some other way of figuring it out; maybe with a counter and some clever incrementing/decrementing on CellStateChanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Gray

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, i edit the title of my question, the problem is that i can't get back to the original color.

Comment: do you mean that you want the last cell clicked to back to it's original color? or the current clicked one?